# access and click buttons without ID or class tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how do i click the button(LayersWidget) in the below html code which doesnt have id or classname.

code is provided below screenshot with highlighted in red.

[image]

as i am unable to find the id, i cannot click it using Javascript code

Comment: It does have a class?  `class="layersWidget"`?

Comment: What do you want to do? Have you looked in to `onclick='MyFunction() ' `?

Comment: I mean `$('#mainMenu .layersWidget')` seems like a valid selector.

Comment: Off-topic particularly, but not generally: A `div` and an `hr` inside a `ul` before (and after!) its `li`s is asking for trouble. If your framework forces that on you, they should be fined .. but whattya gonna do. But if not, move them outside the UL, into the containing DIV.

Answer (score 4):

So in your case, the element does have a class, but you could also select the element by another attribute such as the `data-dojo-attach-point` attribute:

```
$('li[data-dojo-attach-point="LayersWidget"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select it using jquery and the data attribute as the selector

```
$('[data-dojo-attach-point="LayersWidget"]').on('click', function() {});
```

Comment: Avoid using `*` as part of selectors.  And in fact it doesn't offer any extra functionality to this selector and can be removed.

Comment: Updated! Thanks!

Comment: Good to avoid unnecessary jQuery. (No idea if OP can/does use it alongside Dojo.)

Comment: If the goal was to not use jQuery, then the question should not have tagged it with jQuery. @D_N  This question is very confusing given that the premise of not having a class is not true.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to access the element using the code

```
var elmnt1 = document.querySelector('[title="Table of Contents"]');
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use the class?

Comment: You can literally access it through any attribute (though `data-` ones may be more stable; `title` seems particularly fragile) as jspcal's answer states. And there is a class.

Comment: i want to js instead of combining my jquery as my entire application is written in JS. so i used above pattern.

Comment: my usual pattern of code written in appln is using id or class. thats why i was looking for it.

Comment: @vinodhkumarramamoorthy not using jQuery does not mean you cannot look up element by class.  `document.querySelector('#mainMenu .layersWidget')` is perfectly valid and is not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

i use the below code to click the element which i got from one of the answer from above.

```
$('li[data-dojo-attach-point="LayersWidget"]').click();
```